# Masonry script in wordpress theme images stacking at the top

Tags: wordpress, jquery-masonry

I have a wordpress theme with a masonry script that breaks, making the images overlap at the top every time I refresh the page. I have been through loads of questions on here and other forums and can't seem to fix it..

The heights of the images are different sizes so I have to set it to auto in css but I makes the images stack. I've tried different image pre-load plugins and tried to implement scripts but i'm not sure how, so when I try they don't work.

Does anyone know of a good answer that means I can keep the images different sizes, or can anyone explain how to put in a script that will make it work?

I can post my css if anyone needs it.

The site is [www.filthyboy.co.uk/test](http://www.filthyboy.co.uk/test) , any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load your custom javascript after the masonry script. And if that not solve the problem, try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#id').masonry({
    // your options...
  });
});
```

Comment: Or your `<body>` fadeIn will break the masonry script.

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to explain how to add the javascript before the masonry? Do i need to enqueue it? Or can I just add it to the header.php?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script('prettyphoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js');` do i put it after this?

Comment: Yes, you must edit your header.php. First you must load the jquery script, then your masonry script and after that you can load your custom.js. In this custom script you can start with the `$(window).load(function(){//etc..});`